# Recursive function runtime

Tags: algorithm, big-o

1.Given that `T(0)=1, T(n)=T([2n/3])+c` (in this case `2n/3` is lower bound). What is big-Θ bound for `T(n)`? Is this just simply `log(n)(base 3/2)`. Please tell me how to get the result.

2.Given the code

```
void mystery(int n) {
   if(n < 2)
      return;
   else {
      int i = 0;
      for(i = 1; i <= 8; i += 2) {
         mystery(n/3);
      }
      int count = 0;
      for(i = 1; i < n*n; i++) {
         count = count + 1;
      }
   }
}
```

According to the master theorem, the big-O bound is n^2. But my result is log(n)*n^2 (base 3) . I'm not sure of my result, and actually I do not really know how to deal with the runtime of recursive function. It is just simply the log function?

Or what if like in this code `T(n)=4*T(n/3)+n^2`?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), the recurrence solves to c log<sub>3/2</sub> n + c. To see this, you can use the iteration method to expand out a few terms of the recurrence and spot a pattern:

> T(n) = T(2n/3) + c
>
> = T(4n/9) + 2c
>
> = T(8n/27) + 3c
>
> = T((2/3)<sup>k</sup> n) + kc

Assuming that T(1) = c and solving for the choice of k that makes the expression inside the parentheses equal to 1, we get that

> 1 = (2/3)<sup>k</sup> n
>
> (3/2)<sup>k</sup> = n
>
> k = log<sub>3/2</sub>

Plugging in this choice of k into the above expression gives the final result.

For (2), you have the recurrence relation

> T(n) = 4T(n/3) + n<sup>2</sup>

Using the master theorem with a = 4, b = 3, and d = 2, we see that log<sub>b</sub> a = log3 4 < d, so this solves to O(n<sup>2</sup>). Here's one way to see this. At the top level, you do n<sup>2</sup> work. At the layer below that, you have four calls each doing n<sup>2</sup> / 9 work, so you do 4n<sup>2</sup> / 9 work, less than the top layer. The layer below that does 16 calls that each do n<sup>2</sup> / 81 work for a total of 16n<sup>2</sup> / 81 work, again much work than the layer above. Overall, each layer does exponentially less work than the layer above it, so the top layer ends up dominating all the other ones asymptotically.

Comment: 1)For the answer of question 1. Why do we have to make (2/3)^kn=1? And how do you make from this step to the result? Can you explained to me more detailed?

Comment: And what if thr question 2)ask for the big theta notation,then what is the result?

Comment: For (1), you're ultimately trying to figure out when the recursion terminates, and that happens when the size of the input drops down to 1. Therefore, you're solving for the k where n (2/3)^k = 1; that's the point where the recursion stops. For part (2), the solution I've given is asymptotically tight. You can rewrite it using theta notation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some complexity analysis, and we'll find that the asymptotic behavior of `T(n)` depends on the constants of the recursion.

Given `T(n) = A T(n*p) + C`, with `A,C>0` and `p<1`, let's first try to prove `T(n)=O(n log n)`. We try to find `D` such that for large enough `n`

```
T(n) <= D(n * log(n))
```

This yields

```
A * D(n*p * log(n*p)) + C <= D*(n * log(n))
```

Looking at the higher order terms, this results in

```
A*D*p <= D
```

So, if `A*p <= 1`, this works, and **`T(n)=O(n log n)`**.

---

In the special case that `A<=1` we can do better, and prove that **`T(n)=O(log n)`**:

```
T(n) <= D log(n)
```

Yields

```
A * D(log(n*p)) + C <= D*(log(n))
```

Looking at the higher order terms, this results in

```
A * D * log(n) + C + A * D *log(p) <= D * log(n)
```

Which is true for large enough `D` and `n` since `A<=1` and `log(p)<0`.

---

Otherwise, if `A*p>1`, let's find the minimal value of `q` such that `T(n)=O(n^q)`. We try to find the minimal `q` such that there exists `D` for which

```
T(n) <= D n^q
```

This yields

```
A * D p^q n^q + C <= D*n^q
```

Looking at the higher order terms, this results in

```
A*D*p^q <= D
```

The minimal `q` that satisfies this is defined by

```
A*p^q = 1
```

So we conclude that **`T(n)=O(n^q)`** for **`q = - log(A) / log(p)`**.

---

Now, given `T(n) = A T(n*p) + B n^a + C`, with `A,B,C>0` and `p<1`, try to prove that `T(n)=O(n^q)` for some `q`. We try to find the minimal `q>=a` such that for some `D>0`,

```
T(n) <= D n^q
```

This yields

```
A * D n^q p^q + B n^a + C <= D n^q
```

Trying `q==a`, this will work only if

```
ADp^a + B <= D
```

I.e. **`T(n)=O(n^a)`** if **`Ap^a < 1`**.

Otherwise we get to `Ap^q = 1` as before, which means **`T(n)=O(n^q)`** for **`q = - log(A) / log(p)`**.